# Why don't people pickers work when you set a master page to work with HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: web-part, master-page, css, html

I'm working on a web part for which I've customised the master page to work with both HTML5 and CSS3. The problem in doing this is people pickers now no longer work as they have to be set to master pages of IE-8/9 from what I can tell from my research.

They error with the problem:


**Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined.**

Has anyone found a solution to this as I'd rather not loose my HTML5 and CSS3 compatibility.

Comment: is your people picker inside update panel?it wont work under update panel

Comment: no its not within an update panel in this instance, although they can work inside them with a work around I have used on other projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this has to do with IE9, IE10, IE11 document standards for the client's browser.
The problem is in the pickerdialog.master.

As the People Picker is using the pickerdialog.master file, you need to add the following line in the head element.

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"

Find the pickerdialog.master file in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS and make a backup.

Now open it and insert the line at the start of the head element.

```
< head>
< meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
 ....
< /head>
```

Followed by iisreset this should solve the problem in People Picker. This is yet a short-term solution as the mentioned file may be subject to change once Microsoft updates are applied.

[Reference](http://www.sharepointlms.com/helpdesk/knowledgebase_detail.php?ref=UIZ-799)

Answer (score 0):

I am using PeoplePicker with HTML5and CSS3, this is my function to inizialie it and get the value:
Use the function initializePeoplePicker to inizialize the picked. 
The argument is the DIV id.

To get the value of the picker, use the fucntion getUserInfo().

```
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {
    Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';

     Render and initialize the picker. 
     Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
     PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
     picker properties.
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
}

function getUserInfo() {
    var responseUser = "";
     Get the people picker object from the page.
    var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
     Get information about all users.
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    if (users.length == 0) {
        //no users
    }
    var userName=users[0].Key;
}
```